# Converting output of sql query

Tags: sql, xml

Let say I have table

```
 Payments

Id int autoincement
Status int
```

and my query is :

```
select id, status from payments
```

but I wanna convert status to enum.

```
0 is unpaid
1 is paid.
```

so result should look like:

```
1 paid
2 unpaid
3 paid
...
```

I need this conversion because I use

```
XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
oc.LoadXml("<results></results>");

XmlNode newNode = doc.ReadNode(reader);

while (newNode != null)
{
  doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newNode);
  newNode = doc.ReadNode(reader);
}
```

and then I save this xml and opening it by excel, and statuses should be friendly for user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select Id,
case status when 0 then 'unpaid' when 1 then 'paid' else 'unknown' end as Status
from Payments
```